# Regex to accept matches only two formats: string.string and string@string.com

Tags: regex, string

I need a regular expression to accept only two below formats:

```
string.string
string@string.com
```

I have used a pattern but it only accepts this format: `string@string.com`

How to update this pattern

```regex
/^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?[ ]*$/g
```

to accept both of the formats.

Comment: What is your regex flavour?

Comment: If you're validating e-mails, you might be interested in http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html and [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/5290909)

Comment: Thanks. This is very much described. i will look into it. however, i have created a regular expression so far so good for the requirement as i am running out of time. `(^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?[ ]*$)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: It looks like you're reinventing the wheel, with an expresssion that would probably fail (of course, that depends on your scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have updated the pattern which accepts both the formats, now.

Below is the pattern to accept both the format. i.e. abc.def and string@testdomain.com

```
/(^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&\'*+\\/=?^_`’{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?[ ]*$)|([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this way [simpler version](https://regex101.com/r/eD9gM0/2):

```
^\w+[.]\w+$|^\w+@\w+[.]com$
```

Correction thanks to [Mariano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5290909/mariano)

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work for **string.string@string.com**. By string, i meant that it can be anything like abc_def@test.com or abc.def@ert.com etc...

Comment: and abc+def@ghi.com is valid?

Comment: No, i want only two formats.     **anything without characters (dot) anything without characters**      AND  **anything without characters (@) anything without characters (dot) com**

Comment: @user2632691 you want to validate email, don't you?

Comment: i want to use email but at the same time, if a user does not have an email, then he can use this EMAIL field in DB as a username but his username should be his firstname.lastname , then.

Comment: @user2632691 then here's the [full regex email validation](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) and I recommend you to read [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Regex](http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) because it's anything but simple :)

Comment: hahaha. Okay. But client requirement is as such i described in above comment. Thanks

Comment: Ya exactly in many cases But this case can be achieved, i think.

Comment: @Owais then would `jean.paul.sarte@gmail.com` be a valid address? (ie: multi dot before @)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\s*\w+(?:\.\w+|@\w+\.com)\s*$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can replace `\w+` with a character class (`[\w.|]+` for example) to add other accepted characters.

Comment: How do you generate this description ? looks really nice